# Align variables horizontally in unity inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, inspector

I'm writing a very simple class for storing data (at least, for now) for use in a Unity project to do with a learning AI. I want to be able to easily customize multiple agents in the inspector and the number of checkboxes stacked vertically makes this part of my project dominate the inspector. If I could simply have one section make use of the ample empty space on the right side of the inspector, that would be considerably less ugly.

I've been reading a lot about custom property drawers and inspector windows, but it seems like a lot of work, involving rewriting how the entire class is displayed, for one change.

[image]

For reference, here is the class itself.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class NNInfo
{
    public string networkName = "Agent";

    [Header("Movement Properties")]
    public float movementSpeed = 10f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;

    [Header("Learning Properties")]
    public float learningRate = 0.1f;
    public float momentum = 0f;
    public Rewards rewardFunc;
    public int[] hiddenLayers;

    [Header("Other Properties")]
    public int maxHealth = 1000;

    [Header("Optional Inputs")]
    public bool m_PointToNearestBall = false;           // input which is 1 while the agent is facing a ball and -1 when facing away
    public bool m_DistanceToNearestBall = false;        // input which is 1 while the agent is at the ball and -1 when at max possible distance away
    public bool m_PointToEndzone = false;               // similar to m_PointToNearestBall but for the endzone
    public bool m_Position = false;                     // two inputs which inform the player of its normalized x and y coordinates on the field
    public bool m_WhetherHoldingBall = false;           // tells the player whether its holding a ball
    public bool m_CanSeeHealth = false;                 // Whether the player can know its own health

    [Header("Optional Outputs")]
    public bool m_ForwardLeft = false;                  // turn left and move forward simultaneously
    public bool m_ForwardRight = false;                 // turn right and move forward simultaneously
    public bool m_Reverse = false;                      // move backwards
    public bool m_Flip = false;                         // instantly switch to opposite direction
    public bool m_TurnToBall = false;                   // instantly turn to face nearest ball
    public bool m_TurnToLeft = false;                   // instantly turn to face left side of field
    public bool m_Attack = false;                       // attack a player (or idle if no contact)
}
```

Comment: This is a really cool idea but I don't think it's possible (in an easy way).

Comment: I think this is subject doesn't belong to SO. Since, the question is about Unity Dev tool, it's not directly related to pure programming. It should belong to Game Dev (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or why not on Unity Answers website (http://answers.unity3d.com/).

Comment: to accomplish that you need to update the Editor code (or write your own functions). it isn't very difficult and there are many tutorials online.

Answer (score 4):

Custom Property Drawer is keyword which should be interesting for you.

Writing your own code for managing those - lets you describe how you want to show your properties inside Inspector View in Unity editor.

To start, go to official [documentation site,](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) which contains code you can base on.

Code snippets (Javacrpt, c# version can be found under the link):

**Object's code:**

```
enum IngredientUnit { Spoon, Cup, Bowl, Piece }

// Custom serializable class
class Ingredient extends System.Object {
    var name : String;
    var amount : int = 1;
    var unit : IngredientUnit;
}

var potionResult : Ingredient;
var potionIngredients : Ingredient[];

function Update () {
    // Update logic here...
}
```

**Editor code:**

```
@CustomPropertyDrawer(Ingredient)
class IngredientDrawer extends PropertyDrawer {

    // Draw the property inside the given rect
    function OnGUI (position : Rect, property : SerializedProperty, label : GUIContent) {
        // Using BeginProperty / EndProperty on the parent property means that
        // prefab override logic works on the entire property.
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty (position, label, property);

        // Draw label
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel (position, GUIUtility.GetControlID (FocusType.Passive), label);

        // Don't make child fields be indented
        var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

        // Calculate rects
        var amountRect = new Rect (position.x, position.y, 30, position.height);
        var unitRect = new Rect (position.x+35, position.y, 50, position.height);
        var nameRect = new Rect (position.x+90, position.y, position.width-90, position.height);

        // Draw fields - passs GUIContent.none to each so they are drawn without labels
        EditorGUI.PropertyField (amountRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("amount"), GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField (unitRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("unit"), GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField (nameRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("name"), GUIContent.none);

        // Set indent back to what it was
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;

        EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
    }
}
```

[image]